# One pass rendering with GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY

Tags: cubemap

I try to rework rendering of point light shadows from "pass per cube face" to "one pass using geometry shader".

initialization:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, texId);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, getWidth(), getHeight(), 6 * lightsNumber, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, (ByteBuffer) null);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, 0);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, texId, 0);

int status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
   throw new IllegalStateException("Could not create FrameBuffer: " + status);
}

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

using:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, shadowBuffer.getTexture().getId(), lightNumber);

glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

renderMeshes(scene, transformation);

depthShaderProgram.unbind();
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

GS:

```
#version 430

layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices=18) out;

uniform mat4 projLightViewMatrix[12]; // just two light
uniform int lightNumber;

void main() {
  for (int lIdx = 0; lIdx < lightNumber; lIdx++) {
    for(int face = 0; face < 6; face++) {
      gl_Layer = lIdx * 6 + face;
      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        gl_Position = projLightViewMatrix[gl_Layer] * gl_in[i].gl_Position;
        EmitVertex();
      }
      EndPrimitive();
    }
  }
}
```

It casts shadows only for 1st light.
Could you notice something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

What a simple point it was!

```
max_vertices=18
```

18 it is only for one cube! If I need n cubes, then I must emit 18 * n vertices.